# Regex for code formatting

Tags: regex, string, replace, quotes

I would like to add line feed after semi-comas in my text.

Something like `replace(";",";\n\r")`

But i need to exclude the semi-comas inside double quotes, how can i do this with regex?

In case of quotes i want this replacement:

```
var="Hello;World";
var="Hello;World";\r\n
```

and not this:

```
var="Hello;World";
var="Hello;\r\nWorld";\r\n
```

Thnak you!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
s/;(?=[^"\n]*(?:"[^"\n]*"[^"\n]*)*$)/;\n/gm; # perl synax
```

If there are no escaped quotes in the strings, and the strings do not span multiple lines.

That is replace:

```
;(?=[^"\n]*(?:"[^"\n]*"[^"\n]*)*(?m:$))
```

with

```
;\n
```